# Trying To Sort HashMap But Not Produce Correct Result

Tags: android, sorting, hashmap

I have a **HashMap** Which Has **Unsorted values**

```
[{cols=2, row=2},  {cols=0, row=2},  {cols=6, row=1},  {cols=8, row=1}, {cols=4, row=1}
, {cols=10, row=1}, {cols=2, row=1}, {cols=0, row=1}, {cols=8, row=4},  {cols=6, row=2},
{cols=8, row=2}, {cols=4, row=2}, {cols=6, row=4}, {cols=2, row=4}, {cols=10, row=2}, 
{cols=4, row=4}, {cols=10, row=4}, {cols=0, row=4}]
```

When I am trying to sort with cols i got something like this **Sorted value**

```
 [{cols=0, row=2},  {cols=0, row=1},  {cols=0, row=4},  {cols=10, row=1},  {cols=10, row=2}, 
 {cols=10, row=4},  {cols=2, row=2},  {cols=2, row=1},  {cols=2, row=4},  {cols=4, row=1},
 {cols=4, row=2},  {cols=4, row=4},  {cols=6, row=1},  {cols=6, row=2},  {cols=6, row=4}, 
 {cols=8, row=1},  {cols=8, row=4},  {cols=8, row=2}]
```

it should produces 0,2,4,6,8,10 instead of these it produce 0,10,2,4,6,8

My Code for Sorting a **hashmap is**

```
Collections.sort(upperlist, mapComparatorCols)

public Comparator<Map<String, String>> mapComparatorCols = new Comparator<Map<String, String>>() {
  public int compare(Map<String, String> m1, Map<String, String> m2) {
        return m1.get("cols").compareTo(m2.get("cols"));
     }
};
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

UPDATED with a small fix in the code based on comments

As we know that HashMap doesn’t preserve any order by default. If there is a need you need to sort it explicitly based on the requirement using TreeMap or Comparators.

In your case, it sounds you are sorting on string based criteria. With it, 10 comes before 2, etc.

Have your mapped a set of strings or have you converted them in strings in your comparator? It is not clear. Anyhow here it is a quick & dirty solution for both the hypotheses.

if they are really strings:

```
public Comparator<Map<String, String>> mapComparatorCols = 
    new Comparator<Map<String, String>>() {
       public int compare(Map<String, String> m1, Map<String, String> m2) {
          int foo1 = Integer.parseInt(m1.get("cols"));
          int foo2 = Integer.parseInt(m2.get("cols"));
          // two alternative returns

          // faster giving the distance
          return (foo1 - foo2);
          // safer with no distance
          return (foo1 < foo2) ? -1 : (foo1 > foo2) ? +1 : 0;
       }
    };
```

if they are really ints:

```
public Comparator<Map<int, int>> mapComparatorCols = 
    new Comparator<Map<int, int>>() {
       public int compare(Map<int, int> m1, Map<int, int> m2) {
          // change it using ?: operator, if you prefer (see above)
          return (m1.get("cols") - m2.get("cols"));
       }
    };
```

Comment: can you tell me what it does return (foo1 - foo2); ...although your ans is working

Comment: you are right. It was a quick & fast solution. Alternative is a sequence of "if (foo1 < foo2) return -1; else if (....) return +1; else return 0; but I prefers substraction

Comment: now i am changing my code to if (foo1 < foo2) return -1; and its working fine....thank you

Comment: Yes, it is not wrong but keep in mind that "return (foo1 - foo2)" could result in a sensible faster sorting as it gives the distance between foo1 and foo2 and the java sorting algorithm uses isìt (if I remember well my old studies:-)

Answer (score 1):

A HashMap itself cannot guarantee order:

From: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html

> Note that the iteration order for HashMap is non-deterministic. If you want deterministic iteration, use LinkedHashMap.

Or more generally, in the Java documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

If you want to access them ordered, use a [TreeMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TreeMap.html):

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem when i tried this. After some search, I tried below code which is working fine.

```
class MapComparetor implements Comparator<Map<String, String>> {

        private String key = "";

        public MapComparetor(String key) {
            this.key = key;
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(Map<String, String> lhs, Map<String, String> rhs) {
            String firstvalue = lhs.get(key);
            String secondvalue = rhs.get(key);


            if (Integer.valueOf(firstvalue) >= Integer.valueOf(secondvalue)) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
```

It is shorting very well.